# Iterate Through Folders/Subfolders/Files in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Drive structure setup like this:

```
Client A
--Project 1
----Drafts
----Presentations
----Minutes
--Project 2
----Drafts
----Presentations
----Minutes
Client B
<and so on>
```

I want to write a script where I can pass in the ID of Project 1, and it will loop through each of the three subfolders and count the total number of files (ultimately I want to count the number of files updated over a date range, but baby steps!).

I've tried using the Class FolderIterator code, but that wants you to assign a group of folders to a variable "folders" (it showed `var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();` and I tried `var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("<id of Project 1 here>");` but in my version that's just one folder, and it really needs the collection of folders).  Is there a way to assign those three subfolders to that `folders` variable if I have the ID of the parent folder?  Or is there a better way to loop through the subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look some thing like this with DriveApp...

```js
function traverseFolder(folder) {
  var name = folder.getName();

  if ( /^(Drafts|Presentations|Minutes)$/.test(name) ) { 
    var count = 0;
    var files = folder.getFiles();

    while ( files.hasNext() ) {
      count++; 
    }
    Logger.log(name + ' : ' + count);
  }
  var subs = folder.getFolders();

  while (subs.hasNext()) {
    traverseFolder(subs.next());
  }
}
```

We now have access to the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) too. Maybe I'll look at an example with that if some one doesn't post one soon.

Comment: You made a small mistake : `if ( files.hasNext() ) { count++; ` is not an `IF` condition but a `while` loop. I'm sure it is a typo when you wrote the code. Though I upvoted for the idea ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Think I was trying for a `.length` or `.size()` method to begin with instead of looping. Nothing like that to use in this case, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, while is the appropriate tool :-)  DocsList returns arrays and thus allows us to loop in a for/next loop using array.length but not DriveApp.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan--this is great and I appreciate you taking the time!  The code works really well and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Bryan's answer *(thx, I upvoted*) I wrote a test function to see results in the logger and to  run the function with appropriate parameters to get the count you wanted.

*(This answer should not be selected as the right answer since the main part is from Bryan P)*

here is how it goes :

```
    function testTraverse(){
      var originFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Client A').next(); // use the folder name you want here
      var totalCount = traverseFolder(originFolder,0);
      Logger.log('total files = '+totalCount);// note that if some files are
      // in more than one subfolder the count will count every occurrence of 
      //this file so the total might be > to the sum of intermediate values
    }

    function traverseFolder(folder,total) {
      var name = folder.getName();
      var count = 0;
      var files = folder.getFiles();

      while (files.hasNext()) {
        count++; 
      Logger.log('fileName ('+count+') in '+name+' is : '+files.next().getName());

      }
      Logger.log('\n'+name+' has ' + count+' files\n----------------------\n' );
      var subs = folder.getFolders();
      while (subs.hasNext()) {
        total+=traverseFolder(subs.next(),count);
      }
      return total;
    }
```

**Note** that this code will work for a "reasonable" number of files, if you have many files and folders it might exceed the 5 minutes execution time limit.  In this case you'll need to modify it in order to proceed by smaller bunches of files using the token provided  by the method.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you--this is truly incredible...I haven't fully figured it all out yet, but it works like a charm, and I look forward to digging into it and understanding it all.  I appreciate it.  I gave the correct answer to Bryan based on Serge's note but wish I could have given it to both of you.

Comment: This has worked great, though now I'm trying to write all the files to a Google Spreadsheet, and I'm struggling with the counter to keep track of the current spreadsheet row (since the function calls itself, any counter I track gets reset or modified)...is there a way to use/maintain a global counter variable?  Something I could set outside of the function that keeps its value over time?  As a workaround now, I just use the log file, and that works great--just want something a little more user friendly.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... var total is already a global counter... what else exactly do you need ?

Comment: For some reason total remains 0 for me throughout the entire process (I've tried logging it at each iteration and at the end).  I'll go review my code again--maybe I missed something.  Thanks!